# How do i make a global array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I am trying to create a global array using data from a file and use that array for calculations in different functions, e.g. a button click handler. When I use my calculation button it says 'Value cannot be null'.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double size = 0;
    double[] temperture;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileDialog.OpenFile());
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            double size = Convert.ToDouble(line);
            //create array
            double[] temperture = new double[(int)size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                //convert line to double and store in the array
                temperture[i] = Convert.ToDouble(line);
            }
        }
    }

    private void calculateAverageTempertureToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        double sum = temperture.Sum();
        double average = ((double)sum) / temperture.Length;
        textBox1.Text = "Average Temperature = " + average;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as global variables in C#, we call them instance members, you can find more about the structure of a class here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/

Comment: Tip #1: don't call them "voids".

Answer (score 3):

Don't redeclare a local variable for `temperture`:

`double[] temperture = new double[(int)size];`

Re-use the instance variable you already declared as an instance of the class:

`temperture = new double[(int)size];`

Comment: Ohh, Thank you. It Worked!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost done!
Try not to put everything into one procedure.
Google for the SOLID principle and remember the `S`!

In your Form1 class you have fields: `temperture` and `size`. Before you display your form, you want to give these fields a value.

### Ask operator for a file name

To calculate these values, you need a filename. You decided to ask the operator for the filename. So let's create small procedures in your Form1 class that will do this: one to ask for the filename, one to read the contents of the file and one to put this all together:

```
private string SelectFileName()
{
    using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
         // Set properties before showing the dialog, for example:
         dlg.Title = "Please select a file";
         dlg.CheckFileExists = true;
         dlg.InitialDirectory = ...
         // etc. Google: OpenFileDialog class

         // show the dlg, and if user presses OK, return the filename, otherwise null
         var dlgResult = dlg.ShowDialog(this);
         if (dlgResult == DialogResult.Ok)
            return dlg.FileName;
         else
            return null;
    }
}
```

OpenFileDialog is Disposable. Remember to always put IDisposable objects inside a using statement, so you can be certain that it is disposed after use, even if an exception is thrown.

For properties see [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=net-5.0) and the base class.

### Read the file with Temperatures

After the operator selected a file, you can read it. Apparently the first line of the file contains the number of temperatures as a string, every next line contains every temperature in string format.

You decided to use two separate fields: `size` and `temperature`. Know that every array has a property length that holds the number of elements in the array, so you won't need field `size`.

Furthermore, my advice would be to use `List<double>` instead of `double[]`. Only use arrays if you know the size of the array before you create it, and if you are certain that you will never have to change the length. With Lists you won't have to care about the number of elements in it, if you add items, the list automatically changes size.

```
private List<double> Temperatures {get; set;}
```

(or if you want, make it a field: `private list temperatures;)

```
private List<double> ReadTemperatureFile(string fileName)
{
    // TODO: decide what to do if fileName null, or if file does not exist
    // return empty list? or throw ArgumentNullException and FileNotFoundException?

    using (var textReader = File.OpenText(fileName))
    {
        // first line is the expected number of Temperatures in this file
        string firstLine = textReader.ReadLine();
        if (firstLine == null)
        {
            // There is no first line
            // Todo: return empty array or throw DataNotFoundException?
        }

        // if here: the first line has been read
        int expectedNumberOfTemperatures = Int32.Parse(firstLine);
        List<double> temperatures = new List<double>(firstLine);
```

Actually, to create a List, you don't need to know how Long it will be. Adding the expected size to the constructor is only to improve performance.

If you are free to change the format of the temperature files, consider to remove the line with the number of elements and keep only the temperatures. This way, you can avoid the problem that the first line says that there are 100 temperatures, but the file only contains 50 temperature values.

By the way, only use `Int32.Parse(firstLine)` if you are absolutely certain that the first line can be parsed to an int. If you want to handle invalid file formats correctly, consider to use:

```
if (!Int32.TryParse(firstLine, out int expectedNumberOfTemperatures)
{
    // TODO: handle invalid file format; return empty array?
    // throw InvalidDataException?
}
List<double> temperatures = new List<double>(expectedNumberOfTemperatures);
```

By the way: the StreamReader that OpenText returns is IDisposable, so I wrapped it in a using statement.

Continuing reading the file:

```
    string temperatureText = textReader.ReadLine();
    while (temperatureText != null)
    {
        // a line has been read, convert to double and add to array
        double temperature = Int32.Parse(temperatureText);
        temperatures.Add(temperature);
        temperaturText = textReader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Did you see that I didn't care about the actual number of temperatures in the file? If the first line said that 100 temperatures are expected, but in fact there are 200 temperatures, I just read them all, and add them to the List. The List grows automatically when needed.

Of course, if you only want to read 100 temperatures, even if there are still temperatures left, then use a counter and stop when the expectedNumberOfTemperatures are read.

Only use `Int32.Parse` if you are certain that the file contains only valid temperatures, otherwise use `Int32.TryParse` and decide what to do if an invalid line has been read.

By the way, if you use [LINQ](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/what-is-linq), your procedure will be much smaller. Most programmers will immediately know what happens:

(assuming that you can change the file such that it only contains temperatures.)

```
private List<double> ReadTemperatureFile(string fileName)
{
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        .Select(line => int32.Parse(line))
        .ToList();
}
```

In words: read all lines that are in the text file with fileName. Parse every read line into a double and convert the sequence of parsed doubles to a List.

If you really want to return double[], replace the terminating `ToList()` with a `ToArray()`

Or if the first line has to hold the expected number of temperatures and you want to return all temperatures, skip the first line before you convert to doubles:

```
return System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(line => int32.Parse(line))
        .ToList();
```

### Calculate Sum and Average of every sequence of doubles

To make this procedure more reusable, I won't make it only for Lists, or for Arrays, but for every sequence of doubles:

```
private void CalculateAverageTemperature(IEnumerable<double> temperatures)
{
    // using LINQ make this a one-liner:
    return temperatures.Average();
}
```

In fact, I wouldn't even bother to create a procedure for this.

Put it all together:

```
private void FillTemperatures()
{
    string fileName = this.SelectFileName();
    this.Temperatures = this.ReadTemperatureFile(fileName);
    double averageTemperature = this.Temperatures.Average();
    this.textBoxAverage.Text = averageTemperature.ToString();    }
}
```

And finally your event handler:

```
private void OnMenuItemCalculateAverage(object sender, ...)
{
    this.FillTemperatures();
}
```

I separated the event handler from the actual data processing. If you decide to use a button to select a file and calculate an average, changes will be minimal

### Conclusion

Because you separated your code into smaller procedures, that each have only one task, it is much easier for readers to understand what every procedure should do. For you it is much easier to unit test each procedure. If slight changes are needed, for instance you want a button instead of a menu item, or uses type the name of the file in a text box, or you want to support OpenFileDialog as well as a text box with the filename, changes are minimal.

Furthermore: always wrap disposables in a  `using` statement. Use `List<...>` instead of array, and consider to use LINQ to process sequences of similar items.